# EpiServer localization for AJAX pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, episerver, episerver-7

I have a site which uses EpiServer CMS 7.

I have a problem with the language of content which is returned after ajax call. For example, on some page I have a link, after clicking on it the AJAX-request will be sent to the server and content will be returned and inserted in special container.
I have following url for AJAX request:

```
var urlStr= "/Folder1/Ajax/AddSomething.aspx?id=53&epslanguage=en&";
```

This link always contains the CORRECT language in "epslanguage" parameter. But content, which is returned after ajax call, is always in the default language(Swedish).

I have tried to debug and found that on AddSomething.aspx page I have following globalization settings:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture == "sv";
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture == "sv";
EPiServer.Globalization.ContentLanguage.PreferredCulture == "en";
```

Question: how can we set the correct language for the page content? As I understand, EpiServer knows the correct language, but still use "sv" when I call method

```
EPiServer.Core.LanguageManager.Instance.Translate(string str);
```

Thank you all in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the possible [solution](http://world.episerver.com/Modules/Forum/Pages/thread.aspx?id=81183).

I have overridden InitializeCulture() method in the base class(for ajax pages) and used following code:

```
protected override void InitializeCulture() 
{
    base.InitializeCulture();

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = EPiServer.Globalization.ContentLanguage.PreferredCulture;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = EPiServer.Globalization.ContentLanguage.PreferredCulture;
}
```